# installing QGIS on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ssl, certificates, qgis

I installed QGIS on Ubuntu 20.04, and it doesn't really work. I used the advice from the [QGIS website](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#debian-ubuntu).

On the terminal, I have a problem with the QGIS key and keystrings.
When entering these commands:

```
wget -qO - https://qgis.org/downloads/qgis-2020.gpg.key | sudo gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring gnupg-ring:/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/qgis-archive.gpg --import
sudo chmod a+r /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/qgis-archive.gpg
```

the system tells me:

```
neisolsayaparizabi@neisolsayaparizabi-N2x0WU:~$ wget -qO - https://qgis.org/downloads/qgis-2020.gpg.key | sudo gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring gnupg-ring:/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/qgis-archive.gpg --import
gpg: key F7E06F06199EF2F2: 1 Beglaubigung wegen fehlendem Schlüssel nicht geprüft
gpg: Schlüssel F7E06F06199EF2F2: "QGIS Archive Automatic Signing Key (2020) <qgis-developer@lists.osgeo.org>" nicht geändert
gpg: Anzahl insgesamt bearbeiteter Schlüssel: 1
gpg:              unverändert: 1
```

You can see that my system is in German.

It means something like:

```
key F7E06F06199EF2F2: 1 authentication not verified because of missing key.
```

When looking at the list of authentifications, the key in question is there:

[image: screenshot of the list of trustworthy keys - system doesn't allow me to embed pictures]

What can be the problem?

QGIS is installed, but when wanting to connect to a map server, it indicates that this is not possible due to an error in the SSL protocol.

How can I resolve this? I tried to ask the question on the QGIS forum but somehow didn't get admitted.

Comment: Dear all, just a brief addition: I also tried installing QGIS via the Ubuntu Software centre; problem is the same. I do have the key F7E....etcetera.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.20?   Ubuntu uses a *year.month* format.  What is the reason for the 20.20, or is it a typo?  (you have a 2020 in your description, but I don't see the connection with the 20.20 in your heading)

Comment: @guiverc Sorry...20.04

Comment: You can edit your own questions :)   (once corrected I'll remove my comment)

Answer (score 1):

On my system it says:

```
gpg: keyring '/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/qgis-archive.gpg' created
gpg: key F7E06F06199EF2F2: 1 signature not checked due to a missing key
gpg: key F7E06F06199EF2F2: public key "QGIS Archive Automatic Signing Key (2020) <qgis-developer@lists.osgeo.org>" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1
gpg: no ultimately trusted keys found
```

But with the following lines in my `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb [arch=amd64] https://qgis.org/ubuntu focal main # disabled on upgrade to focal
deb-src https://qgis.org/ubuntu focal main # disabled on upgrade to focal
```

QGIS installs fine using `sudo apt install qgis`  giving version 3.14.1

Comment: Dear Ian, I went to /etc/apt/sources.list and found the following:

Comment: something seems to be missing from your comment?

Comment: Too many characters.  QGIS works, but the connection problem to [https://wiki.earthdata.nasa.gov/display/GIBS/Geographic+Information+System+%28GIS%29+Usage#expand-QGIS] persists.   I also went on the QGIS formu and found another user who has the same problem. Apparently it is not an authentification issue, but a problem with the GIBS server (works for other map providers.  Thanks a lot for your help, anyway!

Comment: Sorry. I am still not completely understanding the comment format. I thought I pasted the lines:  'deb https://qgis.org/debian focal main
deb-src https://qgis.org/debian focal main
# deb-src https://qgis.org/debian focal main
deb [arch=amd64] https://qgis.org/ubuntu focal main # disabled on upgrade to focal
deb-src https://qgis.org/ubuntu focal main # disabled on upgrade to focal'

Comment: so did your install of QGIS work?